# Как получить список установленных программ на х64 винде?

Tags: c#, реестр

При запросе типа

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
```

все равно лезет в

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
```

принципиально нужно достучаться до первого пути, ведь по обоим путям есть различия в содержимом.
Заранее огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `Registry.LocalMachine` использовать

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
           RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
           RegistryView.Registry64) // или 32
using (var uninstall = hklm.OpenSubKey(
           @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
{
    // ...
}
```

И не забудьте `using`.

Comment: @joker13-13: Пожалуйста!